# How to call functions inside of objects?

Tags: javascript, function, object

glad i joined this community and hopefully i'll be able to help others someday just as i need help right now.

Into the problem, i am trying to call a function within an object to add a friend, doing so when i check friends total number it doesn't change

Here's the code

```
var facebookProfile = {
    name: "Kareem",
    friends: 300,
    messages: ["Message 1", 'Message 2', 'Message 3', 'Message 4'],
    postMessage: function(message) {
        facebookProfile.messages.push(message);
    },
    deleteMessage: function(index) {
        facebookProfile.messages.splice(index, 1);
    },
    addFriend: function() {
        facebookProfile.friends += 1;
    },
    removeFriend: function() {
        facebookProfile.friends -= 1;
    }
};
```

---- Code that's not working ----

```
facebookProfile.addFriend;
console.log(facebookProfile.friends);
```

---- Code that's not working ----

Always returns the fixed number of friends which is 300, not increasing by 1.
What am i doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to call your method `.addFriend()`

Comment: Could you explain more please?
that's what i get when i try your solution in chrome's console.

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'

Am i doing something wrong or trying in the wrong platform "Chrome's Console"?

Comment: He means `facebookProfile.addFriend()`. He assumed you know javascript well enough to understand that when someone says `.addFriend()` he means `whatever_object_you_have.addFriend()`

Comment: To be clear, javascript is just like most C-like languages such as C# or Java or PHP. `addFriend` is a function. `addFriend()` calls that function.

Comment: Got it, works like charm! It's true i am still new to Javascript. Thank you both!